# Default Gateway not available wireless

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking, router

Thursday I upgraded from windows 8 to Windows 8.1. I was able to configurate everything during install but friday I ran into problems with my network connection.

When I started my pc i couldn't get connected to my wireless network. After some troubleshooting with the build-in functions of windows 8.1 I could find the problem: default gateway not available.

However, my smartphone and any other devices were able to connect to the internet wireless. And on top of it I could connect to the internet by plugging a cable between the router I connect to and my pc. And even by trying another network (thanks to my friendly neighbor who did not secured his network) I was able to connect to the internet.

I have tried a lot of thing found on the internet:

- add NetBIOS to registrykey HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Winsock\Parameters\Transport
- Restart everything (router, modem, PC, ...)
- malwarescan (Malwarebytes found nothing)
- Cleaning up everything unneccesary (Ccleaner, also in registry)

Below you can find a log of ipconfig/all while connected to the wifi.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. Alle rechten voorbehouden.

C:\Users\jeroe_000>ipconfig/all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : PCJEROEN
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : Belkin

Wireless LAN adapter LAN-verbinding* 12:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 42-2C-F4-02-84-A5
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter Bluetooth-netwerkverbinding:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Bluetooth-apparaat (Personal Area Network
)
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : CC-52-AF-A8-71-B5
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : Belkin
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Broadcom 802.11n-netwerkadapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 40-2C-F4-02-84-A5
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::9c89:d597:2adb:d079%4(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.7(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : zaterdag 19 oktober 2013 13:26:23
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : dinsdag 25 november 2149 19:54:55
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 322972916
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-19-BC-9B-71-10-1F-74-0E-21-64

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : Belkin
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GBE Family-controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 10-1F-74-0E-21-64
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.Belkin:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : Belkin
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter LAN-verbinding* 13:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

C:\Users\jeroe_000>
```

Comment: I have no answers yet, but FWIW I've experienced the same problem. Seems to be an actual bug in the Windows 8.1 drivers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem, which I seem to have resolved by updating my driver. If you have one of the following wireless adaptors, I'm guessing that you have the same issue:

```
Intel® Centrino® Advanced-N 6205
Intel® Centrino® Advanced-N 6235
Intel® Centrino® Ultimate-N 6300
Intel® Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260
Intel® Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260 for Desktop
Intel® Dual Band Wireless-N 7260
Intel® Wireless-N 7260
```

I found this problem acknowledged in [this thread on the Intel forums](https://communities.intel.com/message/205842), and the updated drivers can be downloaded here:

https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?DwnldID=23065

(I don't know why this driver isn't yet available through the normal Windows driver updates, but so it goes.)

Comment: I've also had problems with NIC's randomly stop working in Windows, and reinstalling the drivers is a good start. You could use a tool like [HWInfo](http://www.hwinfo.com/) to identify your wireless card, or Google search your motherboard/computer.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. This apparently applies also on Broadcom NIC's